# Does Tukey UlrRewrite support port rewriting?

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to map some requests to port 8090. The following rule must be matching, but it's definitely not working. Suggestions?

```
<rule>
    <condition name="port" operator="equal">8080</condition>
    <from>^/external/inquiries/(.*)$</from>
    <to>http://localhost:8090/external/inquiries/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work any better?

```
<rule>
    <condition name="port" operator="equal">8080</condition>
    <from>^/external/inquiries/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="proxy">http://localhost:8090/external/inquiries/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Note: if you're using maven or something similar, you may need to include org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:4.0.4 and commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1 to get the proxy working.